# Erlang equivalent of Haskell's Data.List etc.?

Tags: erlang

As an Erlanger, one thing I envied about Haskell is its modules such as `Data.List`. It is well thought and carefully named, e.g. its `intersperse`, `intercalate`, and `transpose` functions. I wonder if there's Erlang project which tries to collect common data structure and utility implementations and presents them in a concise way.

Comment: Couldn't find anything on http://erldocs.com/ and http://projects.trapexit.org/web/. These are the places I would normally search for libraries in the Erlang world.

Comment: Yeah, I looked there first but failed to find anything. There're bunch of small utilities in http://www.trapexit.org/Special:UserContributions. But again, not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: It looks like this question doesn't actually have an answer. I am voting to close it as "not constructive." @Edward Wang, if you start such a project, feel free to answer your own question with a reference to it and accept that answer once possible.

Comment: Jeremy, I tagged Roberto's answer as accepted anyway. Let's move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can read from here:

http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html

the module contains basic operations on lists. The Erlang equivalent I suppose is the lists module:

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html

They both contain functions to map, reverse, fold and so on.

If a specific function is not there, I would rather implement it and ask the OTP team to integrate it with that module (or in a different module), rather than having an external library providing these functionalities.

Comment: You have implementation of intersperse and intercalate at: https://github.com/tim/erlang-oauth/blob/master/src/oauth.erl

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a sizable subset of `Data.List` as part of my `l` library.
https://github.com/pzel/l